# Can OpenSSL library be fixed against Voltage attack and are either SSL libs also?

Tags: security, ssl, encryption, openssl

I'm no expert, I can't understand the theory in details but it is said [here](http://pronewb.com/how-to-crack-1024-bit-rsa-encryption-by-clusterfck) that OpenSSL has a flaw. What kind of flaw is not clear, can it be fixed?

What about other ssl libraries?

Comment: OpenSSL has had a host of pretty serious vulnerabilities recently. 0.9.8 is now on 'x' - only two releases left before they run out of letters :-)  here's another useful link for vuls http://www.cvedetails.com/product/383/Openssl-Openssl.html?vendor_id=217  As always, keep all the software on your box regularly patched and up-to-date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just update OpenSSL (:
 A patch addressing this vulnerability was issued shortly after it was discovered

CVE-2012-0884: 12th March 2012

See here:
http://www.openssl.org/news/vulnerabilities.html